# Calling PHP Script in ASP.NET forms

Tags: php, asp.net, oracle, web-services

I have bunch of PHP script file such as "Connect_Db.PHP" , "GetCountryList.PHP" , "InsetData_Sample.PHP"

These PHP files does database call and insert data to Oracle db. This PHP file currently used for iPhone and Android as backend script to interact with database to save and populate data to App interface.

I would like to use this same PHP scripts file for ASP.NET forms to save and populate data to Oracle database.

How do i reuse this PHP script file in my asp.net forms.

For example i would like to get_Arealist from oracle db and the php script is as below.

```php
<?php
   
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

   if (isset($_POST['province_id'],$_POST['language'],$_POST['web_username'],$_POST['web_password'])) {
        
        $province_id = $_POST['province_id'];
        $language = $_POST['language'];
      
        $web_username = $_POST['web_username'];
        $web_password = $_POST['web_password'];
        
        include '/connect_awl/a_pass_conditions.php';
            
        if (($web_username == $w_username) && ($web_password == $w_password)) {

            include '/connect_awl/connection.php';

            if ($language == 'AR') {
                $result = oci_parse($con,"SELECT area_id, area_name_ar FROM area_tb WHERE province_id = '".$province_id."' ORDER BY area_name_ar ASC");
                oci_execute($result);

            }else {
                $result = oci_parse($con,"SELECT area_id, area_name_en FROM area_tb WHERE province_id = '".$province_id."' ORDER BY area_name_en ASC");
                oci_execute($result);
            } 
        
            $num_rows = oci_fetch_all($result, $res);
           if ($num_rows > 0) {
                oci_execute($result);
                while($row = oci_fetch_array($result)) {
          
                    $areaIDArr[] = $row[0];
                    $areaNameArr[] = $row[1];
                }

               $hallArr = array(
                  'areaIDArr' => $areaIDArr,
                  'areaNameArr' => $areaNameArr,
                  'msg' => 'Done'          
               );
               echo json_encode($hallArr); 

            }else if ($num_rows == 0) {

                $msgArr = array('msg' => 'No Areas');
                echo json_encode($msgArr); 
            }
        
            //Close Connection
            oci_close($con);  
        }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach is to consume these API endpoints from ASP.NET the same way they are consumed from the iOS and Android apps.

One example tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Comment: Dear Zoli, Thanks for the response. I am using ASP.NET web forms (.Net Framework) the article has info on .Net core. Is it possible to do in .Net framework ASP.NET forms

Comment: @Deep Any HTTP client will do the job.